# how to get keys that correspond to different values in two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1 = array('potato'=>1,'tomato'=>2,'apple'=>5,'banana'=>10);
$arr2 = array('orange'=>20,'tomato'=>3,'apple'=>5,'banana'=>20);
```

I need function that would return array('tomato','banana'), consider that it omits keys that don't exist in one or the other array. Apple has the same value in both arrays, so it should be omitted - returned should be only keys whose values differ and are set

Comment: Doesn't 'apple' also exist in both arrays, and thus should not be omitted?

Comment: apple has the same value in both arrays, so it should be omitted - returned should be only keys whose values differ and are set

Comment: I wonder why I got the negative points ...

Comment: Somebody probably thought you didn't describe your problem very well. The editing has helped to describe your problem a bit better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work ([demo](http://codepad.org/OsCt97Hz)):

```
$arr1 = array('potato'=>1,'tomato'=>2,'apple'=>5,'banana'=>10);
$arr2 = array('orange'=>20,'tomato'=>3,'apple'=>5,'banana'=>20);
$result = array_keys(array_diff(array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2), $arr2));
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => banana
)
```

Reference:

- [`array_intersect_key` — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)
- [`array_diff` — Computes the difference of arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
- [`array_keys` — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array3 = array();
foreach(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2) as $key => $v){
 if($array1[$key] != $array2[$key]) $array3[] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
* Returns an array which contains keys which are in both $array1
* and $array2, and which have different values.
*/
function getKeysWhichMatchAndHaveDifferentValues($array1, $array2)
{
    $arrIntersected = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
    foreach($arrIntersected as $key => $value) 
    {
            if($array2[$key] == $value) {
                    unset($arrIntersected[$key]);
            }
    }
    return array_keys($arrIntersected);
}

$arr1 = array('potato'=>1,'tomato'=>2,'apple'=>5,'banana'=>10);
$arr2 = array('orange'=>20,'tomato'=>3,'apple'=>5,'banana'=>20);

$final = getKeysWhichMatchAndHaveDifferentValues($arr1, $arr2);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($final) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do simple loop.

Of course if you will need to compare large arrays, the native PHP functions could help a lot. Still can't answer right now what would be the most optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `array_intersect` and `array_keys`.

```
$arr3 = array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));
```

Comment: it returns also 'apple', so it's not the answer

Comment: -1 because it doesnt do what the OP asks for and if you want to intersect on keys, use `array_intersect_keys`

Comment: Valid feedback - although the question was vague at the time, should have commented to get more information. Also, thanks for the `array_intersect_keys` mention, that completely slipped my mind.